# question about new php syntax involving Return Type Declarations

Tags: php, types

I am reading a book by Brent Roose called Laravel Beyond Crud, in it, on page 34, he lists this example:

```
    public function fromRequest(
       CustomerRequest $request
    ): CustomerData
    {
       return new CustomerData(
           name: $request->get('name'),
           email: $request->get('email'),
           birth_date: Carbon::make(
           $request->get('birth_date')
        ),
      );
    }
```

I can see that Brent is returning a "CustomerData"object, but Im confused from line 4 and beyond.  Is he defining a new Class there with some new fancy syntax?

Comment: The constructor uses named arguments. Thats a php feature since Version 8.0. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments

Answer (score 0):

This new format is using named arguments which is new to php8, you can see more examples here https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-named-arguments.